# Is an Action Bar indispensable?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

Much importance has been placed on this UI element. And for good reason too, as it provides a standard UI element, for developers and users alike. So, please understand that I do not wish to contest its usefulness.

On Action Bar pattern: (taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html))

```
It provides several key functions:

* Makes important actions prominent and accessible in a predictable way 
  (such as New or Search).
* Supports consistent navigation and view switching within apps.
* Reduces clutter by providing an action overflow for rarely used actions.
* Provides a dedicated space for giving your app an identity.
```

> If you're new to writing Android apps, note that the action bar is one
>   of the most important design elements you can implement. Following the
>   guidelines described here will go a long way toward making your app's
>   interface consistent with the core Android apps.

The question:

Is an Action Bar indispensable? Are there functions that cannot be implemented if one chooses to forgo this pattern (may be in navigation dept.)? Would there be any platform or device specific problems?

Comment: it is important for the user experience.

Comment: @blackbelt, the OP already acknowledges the user experience issue. The question being asked is whether there is any functionality that cannot be invoked without it.

Comment: @Trevor I see. Do  you really want to go through this?

Comment: @blackbelt Absolutely true. Oddly enough, user experience is not one of the deciding factors in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not mandated in any way by the Android Platform.  You can very easily accomplish many of the same things designed to be done in the ActionBar on your own (navigation, context information about your app).

You will not have any programmatic challenges doing these things without using the ActionBar.

However, this component is a very important pattern in the Android OS, so you better have a very good reason to not use it, as your app will not 'fit' in the Android ecosystem, which will be a negative user experience.

Bottom line, there is nothing mandating that you must use the ActionBar, and you can accomplish the same actions in other ways, but this is not suggested, you should use it, so your app looks like it fits in the Android ecosystem.

Comment: The primary exception to this would be an app with a highly stylized UI, like those seen in many games, where you would roll your own menu structure that is similarly stylized.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. The application will not be released on Google Play. It'll provide a data and schedule management interface, specific to the client's needs. I agree with your `however` clause. But, given the app's purpose, and restricted user-base, I will not be implementing the Action Bar.

Comment: You likely will have extra work to do these things yourself (the AB has a variety of navigation controls included for free).  Also, regardless of if this app will be deployed to Play Store, it will still be run on Android devices (so the proper user experience is still important).